# animate CSS background appears flickering

Tags: html, css, animation

https://jsfiddle.net/v4ufeuzg/

```css
.bg {
          height: 400px;
          width:200px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/kVSeaKo.jpg) repeat-y center center;
    background-size: contain;
    -webkit-animation: displace 1s linear infinite;
    animation: displace 1s linear infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes displace {
      from { background-position: top center;
      } to { background-position: bottom center; }
    }
    @keyframes displace {
      from { background-position: top center;
      } to { background-position: bottom center; }
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="bg"></textarea>
```

The background flick every time it reached the end of the loop, any way to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think background-position(x, y)

Maybe set the background size, and then animate that distance or a multiple of that distance.

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/VjAQJA

### styles

These are in stylus... but the function should be clear - It's just simplified.

```
@keyframes displace
    from
        background-position: center 100px
    to
        background-position: center 0px

.road
    width: 200px
    height: 400px
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/kVSeaKo.jpg)
    background-size: 200px 100px
    animation: displace 1s linear infinite
```

Also, keep in mind that CSS animations are not perfect.

Comment: Also... check out this awesome road animation I saw:  http://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/jAavkG